# Different ways to print the first 5 multiples of 2 in Java as "*"

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, multiplication, println

I'm trying to write a program that prints the output:

```
**
****
******
********
**********
```

What I came up with:

```
public class Loops {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*" + "*");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");  
    }
}
```

This gives me the desired output, but despite my searching I still don't know how I can modify this code to use multiplication instead of just tacking on another * to the print statement.

Comment: Not exactly clearly what you are trying to achieve, what do you mean by use multiplication. It is a string. How will you use multiplication on it? You could use recursion if you don't want to use loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
   {
       s.append("**");
       System.out.println(s.toString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
public class Loops {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < (2 * i); j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a solution that I was looking for.  Is there a way I could have worded my question to be more specific to this solution?  Thank you.

Comment: @dingbat I'm not sure, but something on the line of "use multiplication of loop indexes somewhere because I am allowed to print only a single * on each println statement" could have been clearer. Btw you can accept my answer if you're satisfied with it.